# WP Site with Swift performance loading unused images

Tags: wordpress, image, lighthouse, waterfall

If someone could help me I would be very thankful.

So my Problem, when looking the Waterfall in Google Lighthouse or on GTmetrix its always showing
that some images are being loaded. Those Images are not used on the landing page.

Sample:

[image]

The Website: [Heilwassersicheldorf](https://www.heilwassersicheldorf.com)

Thanks you